# Question Involving Transitive Elements of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be an inductive set.  Let $T = \{x \in X : x \subset X\}$.  Then let $t \in T$.  My question is why does the following hold: $y \in t \implies y \subset t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t necessarily. Let $a=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, and let $X$ be the inductive closure of $\big\{a,\{a\}\big\}$, so that $X$ is inductive. Let $T=\{x\in X:x\subseteq X\}$; then $\{a\}\in T$. Clearly $a\in\{a\}$, but $a\nsubseteq\{a\}$: the only element of $a$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, which is not equal to $a$, the only element of $\{a\}$.

What **is** true is that $T$ is inductive.

Suppose that $t\in T$. $X$ is inductive, so $t\cup\{t\}\in X$. If $y\in t\cup\{t\}$, then either $y\in t\subseteq X$, or $y=t\in X$; in either case $y\in X$, so $t\cup\{t\}\subseteq X$, and therefore $t\cup\{t\}\in T$. Thus, $T$ is inductive.

Comment: Why in the case that $y \in t \subseteq X$ does this imply that $y \in X$?

Comment: @user1770201: $t\subseteq X$ **means** that every element of $t$ is an element of $X$.