# Question Involving Transitive Sets

Tags: set-theory

In Jech's *Set Theory*, we are asked to show the following two statements:

> **1.3** If $X$ is inductive, then the set $\{x \in X : x \subset X\}$ is inductive.  Hence $N$ is transitive, and for each $n$, $n = \{n \in N
> > : m < n\}$.
>
> **1.4** If $X$ is inductive, then the set $\{x \in X : $x is transitive$\}$ is inductive.  Hence every $n \in N$ is transitive.

Yet haven't we showed $1.4$ the moment we have shown $1.3$ since $\{x \in X : x \subset X\} = \{x \in X : $x is transitive$\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true in general that $\{x\in X:x\subseteq X\}=\{x\in X:x\text{ is transitive}\}$. My answer to [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411931/12042) gives an example in which they’re not equal.